# Vue router go back to previous parent route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

My vue app have Settings page with child routes like settings/user, settings/addUser, etc.
what i want to do is implement a back button such that when user press it they go back to the page they visited settings `this.$router.go(-1)` seem to take me back one page which is not always ideal

for now have

```
<v-btn class="my-2" small fab rounded color="primary" block :to="/home">
  <v-icon color="black">
    mdi-home-export-outline mdi-flip-h
  </v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

this is in `settings.vue` where `<router-view>` is present for child routes to render

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Why don't you just pass the path you want to redirect to?

Comment: @ByScripts I have dynamic home pages for admin and non admins so i want those to go back to respective home pages I've done currently is checked for admin and routed accordingly. I'm asking is there a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if [Navigation Guards](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2020/01/27/closer-look-at-vue-router/) would do the trick? If they are routed back to the home page you can check if they are admin and redirect them to their correct home page from inside the Navigation Guard.

Here is the example from the website I linked:

```html
router.beforeEach( (to, next, from) => {
  if (to.path === '/profile') {
    if (!hasAccess(to.path)) { // just some arbitrary conditional
     next(false) // deny access to this page
    } else {
     next() // keep moving on to next hook
    }
  } else {
    next() // keep moving on to next hook
  }
})
```